# how to copy error messages in the os

Tags: clipboard

Is there any application that will copy the text from an error message box into the clipboard?

Comment: can we assume you're looking for Windows (or Windows-7) software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows, with message dialogs like this:

[image]

You can use Ctrl+C to copy, and when you paste, you'll get this:

```
---------------------------
Message title.
---------------------------
Oops, something went wrong. :-(
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Ctrl-C, then paste it into notepad (or whatever else). It's always worked for me